# Google Maps multiple markers position ZOOM ERROR

Tags: php, javascript, api, google-maps, zooming

I just registered to ask for help with google maps. I'm working on a project that allows me to insert various ads of homes in the google map on my site. I do not know why that position is never correct, at first I tried using the code below ...

Then I had to delete the variables city, street, state, and zipcode why they went to war. But without resolving anything. So go to the link to better understand the situation. The generated code is in the script tag to the top of the map div.

[LINK](http://pineto.contat.eu/?ct_property_type=0&ct_beds=0&ct_baths=0&ct_status=0&ct_price_from=&ct_price_to=&ct_additional_features=0&search-listings=true%2a)

```
<script>var defaultmapcenter = {mapcenter: "<?php echo $ct_options['ct_home_map_center']; ?>"}; google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){ estateMapping.init_property_map(property_list, defaultmapcenter); });</script>

<script>
            var property_list = [];
            var default_mapcenter = [];

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $count++; ?>

                var property = {
                    thumb: "<?php ct_first_image_tn_map() ?>",
                    price: "<?php currency(); ?><?php map_pin_price(); ?>",
                    fullPrice: "<?php currency(); ?><?php listing_price(); ?>",
                    bed: "<?php beds(); ?>",
                    bath: "<?php baths(); ?>",
                    size: "<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_ct_sqft", true); ?> <?php sqftsqm(); ?>",
                    street: "<?php the_title(); ?>",
                    city: "<?php city(); ?>",
                    state: "<?php state(); ?>",
                    zip: "<?php zipcode(); ?>",
                    latlong: "<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_ct_latlng", true); ?>",
                    permalink: "<?php the_permalink(); ?>",
                    agentThumb: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img_resize/timthumb.php?src=<?php the_author_meta('ct_profile_url'); ?>&w=40&zc=1'",
                    agentName: "<?php the_author_meta('first_name'); ?> <?php the_author_meta('last_name'); ?>",
                    agentTagline: "<?php if(get_the_author_meta('tagline')) { the_author_meta('tagline'); } ?>",
                    agentPhone: "<?php if(get_the_author_meta('office')) { the_author_meta('office'); } ?>",
                    agentEmail: "<?php if(get_the_author_meta('email')) { the_author_meta('email'); } ?>",
                    isHome: "<?php if(is_home()) { echo "false"; } else { echo "true"; } ?>",
                    commercial: "<?php if(has_type('commercial')) { echo 'commercial'; } ?>"
                }
                property_list.push(property);

        <?php     
            endwhile; endif;
            wp_reset_query();
        ?>
            </script>
            <script>var defaultmapcenter = {mapcenter: "<?php echo $ct_options['ct_map_center']; ?>"}; google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){ estateMapping.init_property_map(property_list, defaultmapcenter); });</script>



**Javascript:**
---------------

    var estateMapping = (function () {
        var self = {},
            marker_list = [],
            open_info_window = null,
            x_center_offset = 0, // x,y offset in px when map gets built with marker bounds
            y_center_offset = -100,
            x_info_offset = 0, // x,y offset in px when map pans to marker -- to accomodate infoBubble
            y_info_offset = -100;

        function build_marker(latlng, property) {
            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                map: self.map, 
                draggable: false,
                flat: true,
                labelContent: property.price,
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
                labelClass: "label", // the CSS class for the label
                labelStyle: {opacity: 1},
                icon: 'wp-content/themes/reale/images/blank.png',   
                position: latlng
                });

                self.bounds.extend(latlng);
                self.map.fitBounds(self.bounds);
                self.map.setCenter(convert_offset(self.bounds.getCenter(), x_center_offset, y_center_offset));

                var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
                    maxWidth: 275,
                    content: contentString,
                    borderRadius: 4,
                    disableAutoPan: true
                });

                var residentialString = '';
                if(property['commercial'] != 'commercial') {
                    var residentialString='<p class="details">'+property.bed+'&nbsp;'+property.bath+'';
                }

                var contentString =
                '<div class="info-content">'+
                '<a href="'+property.permalink+'"><img class="left" src="'+property.thumb+'" /></a>'+
                '<div class="listing-details left">'+
                '<h3><a href="'+property.permalink+'">'+property.street+'</a></h3>'+
                '<p class="location">'+property.city+', '+property.state+'&nbsp;'+property.zip+'</p>'+
                '<p class="price"><strong>'+property.fullPrice+'</strong></p>'+residentialString+', '+property.size+'</p></div>'+
                '</div>';

                var tabContent =
                '<div class="info-content">'+
                '<img class="left" src="'+property.agentThumb+'" />'+
                '<div class="listing-details left">'+
                '<h3>'+property.agentName+'</h3>'+
                '<p class="tagline">'+property.agentTagline+'</p>'+
                '<p class="phone"><strong>Tel:</strong> '+property.agentPhone+'</p>'+
                '<p class="email"><a href="mailto:'+property.agentEmail+'">'+property.agentEmail+'</a></p>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';

                infoBubble.addTab('Details', contentString);
                infoBubble.addTab('Contact Agent', tabContent);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    if(open_info_window) open_info_window.close();

                    if (!infoBubble.isOpen()) {
                        infoBubble.open(self.map, marker);
                        self.map.panTo(convert_offset(this.position, x_info_offset, y_info_offset));
                        open_info_window = infoBubble;
                    }
                });
        }

        function geocode_and_place_marker(property) {
           var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
           var address = property.street+', '+property.city+' '+property.state+', '+property.zip;

               //If latlong exists build the marker, otherwise geocode then build the marker
               if (property['latlong']) {
                   var lat = parseFloat(property['latlong'].split(',')[0]),
                        lng = parseFloat(property['latlong'].split(',')[1]);
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
                    build_marker(latlng, property);

               } else {
                   geocoder.geocode({ address : address }, function( results, status ) {
                       if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                            build_marker(latlng, property);
                        }
                    });
                }
        }

        function init_canvas_projection() {
            function CanvasProjectionOverlay() {}
            CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
            CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.constructor = CanvasProjectionOverlay;
            CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function(){};
            CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.draw = function(){};
            CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function(){};

            self.canvasProjectionOverlay = new CanvasProjectionOverlay();
            self.canvasProjectionOverlay.setMap(self.map);
        }

        function convert_offset(latlng, x_offset, y_offset) {
            var proj = self.canvasProjectionOverlay.getProjection();
            var point = proj.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(latlng);
            point.x = point.x + x_offset;
            point.y = point.y + y_offset;
            return proj.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
        }

        self.init_property_map = function (properties, defaultmapcenter) {
            var options = {
                zoom: 1,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(defaultmapcenter.mapcenter),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                streetViewControl: false
            };

            self.map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map' ), options );
            self.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            init_canvas_projection();

            //wait for idle to give time to grab the projection (for calculating offset)
            var idle_listener = google.maps.event.addListener(self.map, 'idle', function() {
                for (i=0;i<properties.length;i++) {
                    geocode_and_place_marker(properties[i]);
                }
                google.maps.event.removeListener(idle_listener);
            });

        }

        return self;
    }());
```

Comment: I saw this question yesterday, it may be a bug - however, I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: thanks for attention...i can provide you any code you need, it's changed from yesturday :) I think to re-code all...

Comment: Ah, you asked this yesterday? hrm

Comment: I see how they are changing when you zoom. I'm going to let someone else answer this; I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Christian for the help...i hope to solve this.

Comment: Can you remove some of this code to make it easy to help with your problem? Try to leave only what is necessary. Also, if you could leave a sample of an actual `property` object filled in, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a couple of property objects from your live site and simplified the code. This seems to position the markers correctly. There's too much code in your question to tell exactly where you went wrong, but if you start with this demo, you can add your functionality back slowly and see where it breaks.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

> [image: output]

#### Script:

```js
var property_list = [
        {latlong: "36.738884,15.022705"},
        {latlong: "42.608127,14.067408"}
    ],
    options = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( 36.73, 15.02 ),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map( 
        document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ), 
        options 
    );

for( var index = 0; index < property_list.length; index++ ) {
    var latlong = property_list[index]['latlong'].split(','),
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( latlong[0], latlong[1] ),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker( {position: latlng, map: map} );
    marker.setMap( map );
};
```

#### HTML:

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
#map-canvas { 
    height: 300px; 
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm thinking of redoing it from the script ... but porblema for me is the info window ... so I'm trying to retrieve the script. This is not my code ... I bought a theme for wordpress and custom ... but then I noticed the bug: (I do not want to throw the work done so far.
Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your markers and the javascript-code, all(except one) of the markers are placed at the correct position.

The issue  is your content. You may have noticed that the shadow of the 265k-marker is much darker than the 1k-marker. It's because behind that marker are 8 other markers, **9 of your markers are defined with an equal LatLng**.

Only 1 marker is not shown, it's the marker with an empty latlong. The geocoding fails here because of the missing properties `street,city,state` and `zip`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I'm trying to position the pointer only Latlogn ... so I elimanato variables city, etc. ... say that the error could this be? Many have equal values ​​because I have not entered yet ... As soon as I realized the error I stopped to enter values ​​for the marker (I made them equal)

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
var address = property.street+', '+property.city+' '+property.state+', '+property.zip+', '+property.country;
```

with these lines to remove the fields with empty values

```
        var city    = (property.city.trim() != '')?property.city.trim()+',':'';
        var state   = (property.state.trim() != '')?property.state.trim()+',':''; 
        var country = (property.country.trim() != '')?property.country.trim():'';
        var address = city+state+country;
```